# Image from MYSQL database (PHP, MySql)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to display a image URL from mysql database into my website. It's saved as URL in my database.

```
http://www.upload.ee/image/5697422/prague-1168302_1920.jpg
```

this is the url which should appear as $rida['pilt']

```
    <?php
$paring = 'SELECT * FROM postitus ORDER BY id';
$valjund = $yhendus->query($paring);
while($rida = mysqli_fetch_assoc($valjund))
    ?>

<img class="img-thumbnail" alt="city" src="<?php echo $rida['pilt']; ?>" style="width:250px;height:200px" />
```

Comment: Remove while loop only define your variable $rida

Comment: Is it that hard to check if your query was executed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your code you're getting error undefined index as you're accessing your variable out of while loop. Try below code:

```
<?php
$paring = 'SELECT * FROM postitus ORDER BY id';
$valjund = $yhendus->query($paring);

while($rida = mysqli_fetch_assoc($valjund)) : ?>
    <img class='img-thumbnail' alt='city' src='<?php echo $rida['pilt']; ?>' style="width:250px;height:200px" />
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should recheck $rida. After you use "echo var_dump($rida);", you will know all parameters in array. You can choose trust array